# Developing a Facebook app that will appear in Facebook pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want my Facebook app that I'm developing on, appears as an iframe in several fan pages that I have on Facebook.
is this possible to place a facebook app on a Facebook fan page iframe?

if so will my users need to approve my app on each page or will one-time approval for the app will approve it for him in all my fan pages?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes this is possible, please refer to [Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) and [Apps on Facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) documentation for details on how to do this
2. User only need grant access to application once, on other Pages same application will get all user details (This isn't required, if you application doesn't need user identity to work, you can skip this at all)...

Answer (score 0):

Facebook grants permissions by app id, so no matter how many pages you put that app in, it will only ask for perms on one page.